# Can we actually do rspec testing on ruby if my methods don't have parameters?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, rspec

I have a method but doesn't have a parameter, for example

```rb
def goodbye
    puts ""
    puts "Thank you, #{name} for using our service."
    puts "Good luck with your future trip!"
    puts ""
end
```

How can I do rpsec testing with this method that doesn't have a parameter ?

Alex advised me using the solution:

```
expect(goodbye).to output(/#{name}/).to_stdout
```

so my rspec code is like this:

```
describe "goodbye" do
    
    it "should return goodbye with a name as input" do
        expect(goodbye).to output(/#{name}/).to_stdout
    end
end
```

---

### But I got this error msg:

```
F

Failures:

  1) goodbye should return goodbye with a name as input
     Failure/Error: expect(goodbye).to output(/#{name}/).to_stdout
       `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
     # ./test2.rb:41:in `goodbye'
     # ./spec/tcs_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00211 seconds (files took 0.07718 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/tcs_spec.rb:23 # goodbye should return goodbye with a name as input
```

Comment: can you show what that class looks like?

Comment: I have edited my post so that it gives more clarity

Comment: `expect(goodbye).to output(/#{name}/).to_stdout`

Comment: I got error message using that syntax

Comment: well, i just showed you the syntax, you have to initialize your variables and call the methods from your classes. there is no way for me to give you a working example. I've no idea where `goodbye` is located and where `name` is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will play around more with your solution. need to get my head around this!

Answer (score 0):

`name` is an RSpec method. It can be used outside an `it` to print the name of a spec, like this:

```rb
RSpec.describe Greeter do
  describe "#goodbye" do
    puts "Spec name: #{name}"
  end
end
```

Which will output this: `Spec name: RSpec::ExampleGroups::Greeter::Goodbye`

When your expectation calls `/#{name}/`, you are interpolating a variable called `name` into a regular expression that will match the value of the variable in the `output` of the method `to_stdout`.

And, since you didn't declare a variable named `name`, RSpec tried to call its own `name` method which cannot be executed inside the context of an `it` statement (as the error states).

So, in order to get your test working, you need to declare a variable named `name`. You can do that inside the `it` statement (`name = "skyline"`), or you can do that with a `let` statement. Here's what the latter looks like (along with a `subject` to create the object and call the `goodbye` method...

```rb
RSpec.describe Greeter do
  describe "#goodbye" do
    subject(:goodbye) { Greeter.new.goodbye }

    let(:name) { "skylinerr" }

    it "should return goodbye with a name as input" do
      expect { goodbye }.to output(/#{name}/).to_stdout
    end
  end
end
```

Note that @Alex was close, but not quite right. We need to call `goodbye` from a block (inside curly braces), not as a value (inside parentheses), since we're checking the `output` of the method `to_stdout` rather than the return value of the `goodbye` method which is `nil`.

For completeness, here's the class I wrote to get this test to pass...

```rb
class Greeter
  def goodbye
    puts ""
    puts "Thank you, #{name} for using our service."
    puts "Good luck with your future trip!"
    puts ""
  end

  def name
    "skylinerr"
  end
end
```